Does all UIKit api's need to be ran on the main thread?
I was under the impression that only UI work that is done to alter UI on the screen needs to be on the main thread. I was wondering if even using UIkit component api's are required to, to ensure thread safety
func checkIfUIisVisible() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if self.view.window != nil {
            // The view is currently visible on the screen
            print("UI is visible")
        } else {
            // The view is not visible
            print("UI is not visible")
        }
    }
}

Expecting it to work the same without having to execute on the main thread.

What happened when you tried it? Try deliberately running on global.async instead of main.async. What happens?

Also note that you only need the DispatchQueue thing if you have reason to believe that checkIfUIisVisible() will ever be called not on the main thread. Do you? Because it is utterly ridiculous to get onto the main thread if you are already on the main thread.
